# I want to switch my text input to a drop down list with options -> MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently have a form that has text entries that input properly into a database.

ON the last entry I want to switch it from text input to a drop down list. Here is my current code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="equipment">Equipment:</label>
    <input type="text" id="equipment" name="equipment" value="<?php echo isset($equipment) ? $equipment : ''; ?>" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
    </div>
```

This is the code I tried switching it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showfield(name){

if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';

else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';

}

</script>



<select name="equipment" id="equipment" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

<option value="53V" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53V') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53v</option>
<option value="53R" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53R') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53r</option>
<option value="53F" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53F') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53f</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>

</select>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Am I close at all?

EDIT: I edited based on Raptord's advice

Now I'm getting:

Error 2031
No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

ADDED:

```
CREATE TABLE `details` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `contactname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `equipment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

EDIT (REVISED CODE):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showfield(name){

if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';

else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';

}

</script>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="equipment"><sup>*</sup> Equipment:</label>

<select name="equipment" id="equipment" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="53V" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53V') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53V</option>
<option value="53R" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53R') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53R</option> 
<option value="53F" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53F') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>">53F</option>
 <option value="Other">Other</option> </select> <div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have two `value` attributes in an option.

Comment: Well, you don't want to have two `value` attributes on each `option` element. You're probably wanting to set the `selected` attribute there.

Comment: I'd like to add:The script I have in there is for the "Option" section to drop down a text entry

Comment: What you probably want is `echo $equipment == "53V" ? "selected" : "";`

Comment: Why did you just make that change to your question?

Comment: I removed the first value, I realized there was two of them so I cleared the first one.

Comment: Please do not update your question in a way that invalidates existing comments and/or answers.  Feel free to _add_ new information, but fundamentally changing what's there is generally frowned upon.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, sorry about that. I will add an "EDITED:" section for all future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your option tags should look something like this, rather than having 2 value attributes:

```
<option value="53V" <?php echo (isset($equipment) && $equipment == '53V') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>53v</option>
```

Comment: I edited my original post, any thoughts on this error I'm getting?

Comment: Looks like a mysql-related issue rather than php/html. Would need to see your sql query to be able to help.

Comment: I added the create table, just basic stuff. It worked perfectly with just a regular text submission so I don't think its an SQL issue

Comment: I was able to fix this issue, and it was as you mentioned an SQL issue.
Now it procceses but Equipment appears as "NULL" in the table

Comment: Print the value of your equipment field when you submit the form to make sure you're sending the value you think you're sending. Also make sure you are correctly setting the value in your sql query when updating/inserting the record.

Comment: I added the latest revision of my code, still returning as NULL upon submit. I have other text entries that work just fine, this is the only one causing an issue. My guess is it's something to do with the option value

Comment: Just saw there was an extra quote in the <option> tag I suggested. You'll need to remove the quotation mark immediately after the closing php tag for each option. I don't know if that will fix your issue though. If not, we'd need to see your code that does the insert/update and any processing upstream of that done on the submitted values

Comment: Yea I realized that and fixed it ahead of time, that wasn't the issue however. I'll post my code once I get home from work. Thanks for your help!